# Table view didselectrowatindex returning nil (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController that has a function named didselectrowatindex that should return the text on a cell, but it returns nil. How can I return the text of the selected cell in Swift UITableViewController?

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;
        println(currentCell.textLabel!.text)
    }
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I am using static cells, which means the data is already set so I didn't think there was a need for cellforrowatindex.

Comment: Sorry will edit my question now.

Comment: try to adopt to UITableViewDelegate

Comment: delete the line `let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow();` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to implement cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")
    let text = self.tableContents[indexPath.row] as! String
//tableContents is just the array from which you're getting what's going in your tableView, and should be declared outside of your methods
    cell.textLabel?.text = text
    return cell
}
```

also add

```
self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```

into you viewDidLoad
hope this helps!

## **Edit for static cells:**

Okay, so looking at it that way, maybe try to replace the line

```
let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;
```

with

```
let currentCell = super.tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

and get rid of the line above it as suggested by Lancelot in a comment on your question.

### Edit Two:

I used the following code and it works:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let currentCell = super.tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)

        let text: String = currentCell.textLabel!.text as String!

        print(text)
    }
}
```

Comment: But I am using a UITableViewController, with static cells, so I don't need to add data, do I?

Comment: Okay, so looking at it that way, maybe try to replace the line `let currentCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!;` with `let currentCell = super.tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)` and get rid of the line above it as suggested by Lancelot in a comment on your question. @zach

Comment: @zach, using your code and my edits, I created a project and got it working, I've edited my answer to include the full code. I really hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data source array of the titles as:

```
    var arrTitlesDataSource = ["t1","t2","t3"]
```

So you are using them in order to set the title at the `cellForRow`like this:

```
    cell.textLabel?.text = arrTitlesDataSource[indexPath.row]
```

Than you may get the title in this way:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var title = arrTitlesDataSource[indexPath.row]
    println(title)
}
```

Comment: What if I am using static cells? The cell text is already set.

Answer (score 0):

Get selected row cell from tableView(sender) and then
get your data from selected cell.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


var currentCell= tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)! as tableViewCell

        println(currentCell.textLabel!.text)
    }
```